# Qt Designer - Edit|Edit Signals/Slots

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer

In `Qt Designer`, and when entering the `Edit Signals/Slots` mode, I have two buttons `OK` and `Cancel`.

How can I set the following for the buttons:

**OK**

SIGNAL(clicked())

SLOT(accept())

**Cancel**

SIGNAL(clicked())

SLOT(reject())

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just drag signal emitter to slot owner. You will be presented a list of signals and slots that you may connect from GUI. All others (not displayed) you will have to connect manually (from the code)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using QButtonBox, then click OK will emit accepted() and Cancel will emit rejected().
If you're using QPushButton, then each button emit a clicked() signal.

You just have to connect it to the corresponding slot of the receiver.

Answer (score 0):

There's also a 'Signal/Slot Editor' in which you can add connections without interacting with the form. It's found in View -> Signal/Slot Editor.